# Apache WordPress subfolder .htaccess: DirectoryIndex not allowed here

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a working WordPress site that also serves an old flat-file folder. I have set up a clone environment with Ubuntu 22.04 and XAMPP at home and while the WordPress part is fine trying to access the subfolder causes an error.

```
[Sun Feb 26 17:36:06.779271 2023] [core:alert] [pid 81557] [client 127.0.0.1:37060] /srv/www/site/classic/.htaccess: DirectoryIndex not allowed here
```

The folder has the same `.htaccess` file that works on the public site:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

If I delete `.htaccess` I get this error:

```
[Sun Feb 26 17:42:03.345577 2023] [autoindex:error] [pid 93553] [client 127.0.0.1:48984] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/site/classic/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

However after deleting `.htaccess` while you cannot just go to `http://site.local/classic/` it will work with explicit pages like `http://site.local/classic/index.html`.

I definitely don't understand these errors since one seems to contradict the other.

Since I don't have control over my public host's `httpd-vhosts.conf` I'm assuming the fault lies there but whatever the fix is I'd like to replicate the `.htaccess` file in a subfolder setting `DirectoryIndex` rather than just a single fix for this one subfolder.

Relevant portion of `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "/srv/www/site/"
       ServerName site.local
    <Directory /srv/www/site>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /srv/www/site/wp-content>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Site root `.htaccess` (WordPress default):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Definitely in learning mode here so all advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <Directory /srv/www/site>
>     Options FollowSymLinks
>     AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
>     DirectoryIndex index.php
> ```

To be able to set `DirectoryIndex` in `.htaccess` (specifically, to be able to *override* the `DirectoryIndex` in a `.htaccess` context) you need the `Indexes` *directive-type* in the `AllowOverride` directive. For example:

```
AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo Indexes
```

Or, what you see more commonly, is the use of the `All` keyword (which also includes `AuthConfig` - to allow the use of the authorization directives). ie. `AllowOverride All`.

**Reference:**

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

---

Note that the WordPress config is dependent on `DirectoryIndex index.php` being set (for when the homepage is requested). Which you have set in the server config. You can set both in a single directive, for example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

(`index.php` takes priority in this case.)

If the `DirectoryIndex` is not set *anywhere* then the default is `index.html` only.

Comment: Thanks so much the `Indexes` directive was all that I needed. I'm an IIS guy, need to learn what these directives actually mean 